# setting conditional serializer class removes the custom serializer class for extra action in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have one modelviewset and couple of extra actions for it.

```
class TestViewset(
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    GenericViewSet,
):
    permission_classes = [CustomPermissionClass]

    def get_serializer_class(self) -> Type[ModelSerializer]:
    
        if self.action == "list" or self.action == "get":
            return FirstSerializer
        return SecondSerializer


    @action(
        detail=True,
        methods=["POST"],
        url_path="test-path",
        url_name="test-path",
        serializer_class=MyCustomSerializer,
    )
    def test_path(self, request: Request, **kwargs) -> Response:
        
        print(self.get_serializer()) # Despite setting the 'MyCustomSerializer' it still gives me 'SecondSerializer'
       
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

If I remove the `get_serializer_class` method and give only one serializer it works.

What could be the best solution for this or is this any bug in drf?

Ideally the extra action should use the serializer class that has been provided but its not.

Comment: It's not a bug. This is because `get_serializer_class` will have the last say on what serializer to use. Using it in action like this is the same as setting `serializer_class` in the viewset (which will still be overridden by `get_serializer_class`). I think one thing you can do to fix this is to use `return self.serializer_class or SecondSerializer`, to default to `SecondSerializer` if there's no `serializer_class` set anywhere.

Comment: In your `test_path` action, this should return `MyCustomSerializer` as your serializer

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Thanks @bdbd your solution works if you add that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a better approach for this, but off the top of my head, you can fix this by changing your `get_serializer_class` to:

```
    def get_serializer_class(self) -> Type[ModelSerializer]:
        if self.action == "list" or self.action == "get":
            return FirstSerializer
        return self.serializer_class or SecondSerializer
```

This will ensure the `serializer_class` that is defined in your action is used, if the action is neither list nor get.